# Why do they swap hats in Andor?

Tags: star-wars, andor

In Star Wars: Andor (Episode 12), there is a short scene where Syril Karn and Linus Mosk are sitting side-by-side in a shuttle. They silently exchange hats.

Why?

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaXnJKgx27g

Comment: I've seen a bunch of assertions online; that it was because the hats don't fit, because Linus' hat is scruffy, because there's something written in the lining, to help them identify each other in a crowd. All of these assertions made without a smidge of evidence.

Comment: The ***implication*** from the official audio description is that Mosk feels that Syril's hat better fits his disguise (and vice versa), but there's no positive confrmation > "*On the shuttle ferry, Syril and Sergeant Mosk sit across the aisle from on another. Syril, in buttoned-up civilian attire and Mosk in his smelter's smock. Without meeting each other's gaze, they trade hats across the aisle and peer inside the lining before putting them on."* You might note that Syril is picking at his slightly shabby hat when the scene opens.

Comment: I heard an idea that it was because they would better recognise their own hat on the in other's head in a crowd

Comment: @HorusKol - I've no idea where that idea's come from. Both of them are wearing a hat that came with the outfits. They'd be no more familiar with the swapped hat than their own.

Comment: The glance inside the lining made me think they were passing messages. It's a pretty terrible way to communicate but that sort of fits with these two and their approach to espionage.

Comment: It's not clear why they'd need to pass messages that way. They could speak freely before getting on the shuttle

Comment: I thought you didn't see them speak in-person before they got off the shuttle but I'd need to rewatch the episode to be sure. Either way, it works as part of their bumbling approach, but I know that theory's got no more basis than any of the rest.

Comment: The whole series is about tone, so I doubt it was left in for any mechanical reason like a better disguise. I do like the idea that Linus simply wanted his officer to have a better hat. This would be a subtle way to express their relationship. Problem is, despite the 8 hour run time we barely see them interact, and that was 6 hours and four plot lines ago. So it comes off as just baffling.

Comment: Not addressed in this interview with showrunner Tony Gilroy: http://www.theqandapodcast.com/2022/11/andor-q-tony-gilroy-s1-eps-10-12.html